# AWS File upload using presign URL

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am trying to build a file upload and download app using AWS APi gateway,AWS lambda and S3 for storage.
AWS lambda puts a cap of 6 mb on the file size and  API gateway a limit of 10 mb.
Therefore we decided to use pre sign url for uploading n downloading files.

Step 1- Client sends the list of filename(let's say 5 files) to lambda.
Step 2- Lamda creates and returns the list of pre sign url(PUT) for those files(5 urls).
Step 3- Client  uploads the file to S3 using the urls which it received.
Note - The filename are S3 bucket keys.
Similar approach with downloading file .

Now the issue is with the latency, it takes quite a long time and performance is the collateral damage.

The question is, the above approach the only way to do file upload n download in lambda.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the case of S3 Transfer Acceleration. You'll still create pre-signed URLs but enable this special setting in S3 which will reduce latency.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/transfer-acceleration.html

Alternatively you can use CloudFront with S3 origin to upload / download file. Might have to re-architect your solution but with CloudFront and AWS networking backbone, latency can be reduced a lot.

Comment: I have enabled  Transfer Acceleration and was thinking of using CDN Cloud front service, but is my current file upload design the proper AWS way?

Comment: Well there's no such thing as AWS way. There are various ways of implementing same thing in AWS and it depends on the requirements. You can try both the implementations and see which one works for you both in terms of latency and cost wise.